# Get specific CRM organization instead of all

Tags: dynamics-crm, crm, organization

There are multiple organizations on a CRM on-prem environment. I have stored DiscoveryService URL and organization name in a configuration file.

I want to get an Organization instance for a specific organization using organization name available in the configuration file, instead of loading all organizations.

something similar to,

```
select organizations from Organizations where orgName = 'XYZ'
```

Currently, I am using the below code, which is taking more than 3 seconds to retrieve an instance.

```
private OrganizationDetail DiscoverOrganization(Uri discoveryUri, string organizationName, ClientCredentials lclClientCredentials)
        {
            DiscoveryServiceProxy serviceProxy;
            using (serviceProxy = new DiscoveryServiceProxy(discoveryUri, null, lclClientCredentials, null))
            {
                IDiscoveryService service = serviceProxy;
                var orgsRequest = new RetrieveOrganizationsRequest() { AccessType = EndpointAccessType.Default, Release = OrganizationRelease.Current };
                var organizations = (RetrieveOrganizationsResponse)service.Execute(orgsRequest);
                return organizations.Details.FirstOrDefault(x => x.UniqueName.ToLower() == organizationName.ToLower());
            }
        }
```

Comment: did you try this?

Answer (score 0):

You can try web api version as well. [Read more](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customerengagement/on-premises/developer/webapi/discover-url-organization-web-api#web-api-versioning)

```
GET https://dev.{servername}/api/discovery/v9.0/Instances(UniqueName='myorg')
```

Comment: I am trying to access the CRM Discovery url in custom WCF service. So I don't have user name and password.